# Find the longest String prefix

Tags: java

> Write a function to find the longest prefix of a list of string. For example,
>
> ['abc', 'abcde', 'abxyz'] => 'ab'

So it is an **Arraylist** and we find the longest prefix in the list of strings.

**Let's try Java.**

**Please, no complete solutions**

```
public string prefix (Arraylist<String> lst){

Arraylist<char[]> charLst = new Arraylist<>;

for(int i =0; i < lst.size(); i++){

  charLst.add(lst.get(i).toCharArray());

}

}
```

But how do I proceed after creating a CharArray? This is already starting to be inefficient as it is `O(n)` with just the conversion to CharArray. I would just like some hint/help in the approach

Answer (score 1):

Why do you add the ith character of every string to charLst?  What you need is just the length of the longest common prefix, and then you can output the prefix based on the length you got.